# Time Series Forecasting on call center Data

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have data from a call center morning 8 am to evening 8 pm with half an hour intervals. I am trying to perform time series forecasting to predict expected number of calls during the same time frame in the coming days. I have tried using ARIMA and exponential smoothing but they haven't given me any good results. I am not sure how to bring in seasonality into picture as its only 8 am to 8 pm data. But there are almost no calls on the weekends.
Is there any other algorithm/technique which I should be trying ? Would really appreciate your help. Thanks
I am attaching the screen shot of the data based on time series below. [Image is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMlgu.png)

Comment: If you need recommendations for statistical models for your data, you will get better help at [stats.se] where questions about statistics are on topic. This doesn't seem to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I agree with MrFlick suggestion. Moreover It would be nice to have the temporal scale (the vertical doe not matter very much). You seams to have a 6-cycle period (with an exception on the last cycle). But 6 days is not a week...